# Angular migration to 5.0.0

Tags: angular, npm, migration

Am I the only that got this errors?

```
c:\projects\shop\front-end\node_modules\nan\nan_new.h(208): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'd
ouble', possible loss of data (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\map.cpp) [C:\Projects\Shop\front-end\node_module
s\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\projects\shop\front-end\node_modules\nan\nan_new.h(208): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'd
ouble', possible loss of data (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\list.cpp) [C:\Projects\Shop\front-end\node_modul
es\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\projects\shop\front-end\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::ForceSet': was decla
red deprecated (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\string.cpp) [C:\Projects\Shop\front-end\node_modules\node-sass\
build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\projects\shop\front-end\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::ForceSet': was decla
red deprecated (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\number.cpp) [C:\Projects\Shop\front-end\node_modules\node-sass\
build\binding.vcxproj]
```

https://pastebin.com/SRpV9hYb

All warnings here!

To final are some warnings, it's ok?

Comment: it looks like the sass compiler isnt installed properly, going by the pastebin error

Comment: Warnings are not ok.

Comment: @Iancovici depends on the warning

Comment: @mast3rd3mon so what I should do?

Comment: try to install it

Comment: First, try verifying that you have it by using `npm ls node-sass`. If it doesn't exist, can you try installing it again? `npm install`. Or try rebuilding Node Sass using `npm rebuild node-sass --force`.